# pgfplotstabletypeset verticle alignment of cell contents, plus horizontal lines

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am using `pgfplotstabletypeset` to read contents of a csv file and typeset (In the MWE below instead I copy/pasted the contents of csv file, to make it easier to test the MWE).

I have some content that spans multiple lines in some cells. I use `\makecell` to achieve that.

As a consequence, when a cell on the same row with a multiline cell has single line content I see empty spaces above and below it. Obviously default vertical alignment is centering in this case.

When typeset, the rows are not easily separated visually anymore. To remedy that, a) I want all cells (except header cells) to be vertically aligned to top. b) And/or (depends on how it will look) I may want horizantal cell borders to be visible, as in putting `\hline`s between each row in normal `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{makecell}
\title{A}
\author{E}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Coefficient Generated Table} 
    \label{tab:Data} 
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
      col sep=semicolon,
      string type,
      every head row/.style=
        {before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
      every last row/.style=
        {after row=\hline},
   ]{
    Name;W;aaaa
    s;\makecell{400, 300 \\ 500, 200 \\ 2, 32, 532};23
    d;124 234;234
}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a `hline` after each row using: `every first row/.style={after row=\hline}`

### Result

[image: hline]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            col sep=semicolon,
            string type,
            every head row/.style=
            {before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
            every first row/.style={after row=\hline},
            every last row/.style=
            {after row=\hline},
        ]{
            Name;W;aaaa
            s;\makecell{400, 300 \\ 500, 200 \\ 2, 32, 532};23
            d;124 234;234
        }
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

But you can also change the separation between the different rows by using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`. Change the number to your liking.

### Result

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            col sep=semicolon,
            string type,
            every head row/.style=
            {before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
            every last row/.style=
            {after row=\hline},
        ]{
            Name;W;aaaa
            s;\makecell{400, 300 \\ 500, 200 \\ 2, 32, 532};23
            d;124 234;234
        }
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

I could not find a way to change the vertical alignment with `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This resolved several issues I was running into.  I will have to explore your MWE further and it looks like a good template for making tables.

Comment: @G.Khanna No problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with your example -- and thank you again!  It looks like using pgfplottable, \arraystretch, \makecell, and \Gape, you can solve a lot of problems that I've seen others try and tackle with pgfplotstable.

Just for your reference, here is an example that I recently built

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{table}[htpb]
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        col sep=&,
        row sep=\\,
        string type,
        every head row/.style=
        {before row=\toprule, after row=\bottomrule},
        every last row/.style=
        {after row=\hline},
]
{
Symbol & Symbol Name & Definition, Meaning & Examples \\
       \{ \}  & set & \Gape[4pt]{\makecell{A collection of elements \\ (not    necessarily ordered)}} &  \makecell{$A = \{3,7,9,14\}$ \\ $B = \{9,14,28\}$ } \\ \hline
       \makecell{$\in$ \\ $\notin$}  & \makecell{\bf element of \\ \bf not element of} & set membership &  \makecell{$x = 3 \in A$ \\ $x = 28 \notin A$} \\ \hline
\makecell{$\exists$}  & there exists & \makecell{ {} \\ {}  } &  \makecell{if $x \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\exists\ x > 0$} \\  \hline
\makecell{$\mid$}  & such that & \makecell{further define \\ characteristics of object} &  \makecell{$A = \{ x \mid x \in \mathbb{R},\ x \leq 0 \} $ } \\ \hline
\makecell{$\cap,\ \bigcap$}  & intersection & \makecell{objects that belong to \\ two or more sets}  &  \makecell{$A \cap B = \{ 9,14 \} $ } \\ \hline
\makecell{$\cup, \bigcup$}  & union & \makecell{objects that belong to \\ one or more sets}  &  \makecell{$A \cup B = \{ 3,7,9,14,28 \} $ } \\ \hline
\makecell{$\subset$}  & strict subset & \makecell{one subset has fewer \\ elements than the other}  &  \makecell{ $\{9,14\} \subset \{9,14,28\}$ } \\  \hline
\makecell{$\subseteq$}  & subset & \makecell{one subset has fewer  or equal \\ elements than the other}  &  \makecell{ $\{9,14,28\} \subseteq \{9,14,28\}$ } \\  \hline
\makecell{$\supset$}  & strict superset & \makecell{one subset has more \\ elements than the other}  &  \makecell{ $\{9,14,28\} \supset \{9,14\}$ } \\ \hline
\makecell{$\supseteq$}  & superset & \makecell{one superset has more  or equal \\ elements than the other}  &  \makecell{ $\{9,14,28\} \supseteq\{9,14,28\}$ }  \\ \hline
\makecell{$\emptyset$}  & empty set & nothing to see here  &  \makecell{$A = \{2,4,6,8\}$ \\ $B = \{1,3,5,7\}$ \\ $A \cap B = \emptyset$  }  \\
}
\caption{Common notation and symbols used in set theory.}
\label{tab:set_notation_1}
\end{table}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

In addition to what you described, note a few things that I was able to do quite easily:

- Bold the text of a single element in the table
- \arraystretch gives me good spacing on the rows which don't have multi-line input
- For rows with multi-line input (ex Rows 4 - 10), the text runs into the line dividing the rows.  To correct for this, we can use the \Gape command (part of the ]makecell package) to add space.  I have done that for the multi-line input in the first row (the deinition / meaning of set) so you can see the distiction between the first row and Rows 4 - 10.
- \makecell makes it very easy to insert formulas into the cells.  Just be careful that you have to enter the $ within the \makecell!

Thank you again!